# Failed to load source for dependency `frame-benchmarking`

Tags: substrate-node-template, polkadot-sdk

I'm trying to upgrade a repo based on the [Node template at Developer Hub](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template). This template hasn't been updated and dependencies refer to the archived SDKs instead of polkadot-sdk.

I tried to change that in my repo, but it results in the following error:

```
error: failed to get `frame-benchmarking` as a dependency of package `node-incentiverse v0.1.0 (/Users/arjanvaneersel/Development/rust/node/node)`

Caused by:
  failed to load source for dependency `frame-benchmarking`

Caused by:
  Unable to update https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0

Caused by:
  failed to find branch `polkadot-v1.0.0`

Caused by:
  cannot locate remote-tracking branch 'origin/polkadot-v1.0.0'; class=Reference (4); code=NotFound (-3)
```

Additionally I ran `cargo clean`, removed cargo's registry, as well as Cargo.lock before running `cargo check --release` again.

All Cargo.toml files, respectively in `node`, `pallets` and `runtime` declare the dependency as follows:

```
frame-benchmarking = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, optional = true, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
```

with the exception that only the pallets version uses `default-features = false, optional = true`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`polkadot-v1.0.0` branch is in old, archived [repo](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/polkadot-v1.0.0), this is why it can't find it in `polkadot-sdk`. Try higher versions, i.e [`release-polkadot-v1.1.0`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/tree/release-polkadot-v1.1.0) if you want to use `polkadot-sdk`.

Comment: That was the solution indeed. That also means that there's an error in the nicks pallet tutorial in the documentation, since that's where I got the structure from in the first place.

In the example it says: `pallet-nicks = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }` of which `polkadot-v1.0.0` should also be `release-polkadot-v1.1.0`.